# Missing entries in the stack trace in Erlang

Tags: erlang, stack-trace, inlining

When I compile the following module:

```
-module(x).
-export([inp/0]).

f(X) ->
    g(X).

g(X) ->
    error(X).

inp() ->
    f(123).
```

And evaluate `x:inp()` I get the following output:

```
[{x,g,1,[{file,"x.erl"},{line,8}]},
 {erl_eval,do_apply,6,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,689}]},
 {erl_eval,try_clauses,8,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,919}]},
 {shell,exprs,7,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,686}]},
 {shell,eval_exprs,7,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,642}]},
 {shell,eval_loop,3,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,627}]}]
```

Where did the calls to `f` and `inp` go? This behavior makes it significantly harder to track the causes of errors in my case, how can I get the full stacktrace?

---

I am using OTP24

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56019718/113848) answer your question? It's a question about Elixir, but the answer applies to Erlang as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of Erlang's compiler optimization. The compiler deduces that, **in this specific case**, functions `f()` and `inp()` are only used to pass a number to function `g()` and they cannot be used for anything else, not even theoretically. So the compiler "optimizes them away" and de facto only compiles function `g()`.